# BlackBerry Enterpise Server 5.0 (With Exchange 2010) stops delivering emails after a few hours

Tags: email, exchange-2010, bes

Our setup before used to be like this:
- Exchange 2007 with BlackBerry Enterprise Server 5.0
Everything was working fine and good, but once we changed to Exchange 2010 with the same BES server the problems started coming in.

The BES server would be working fine and good but after a few hours, it would just stop delivering mails. All services would be still in running mode and nothing in the Event log would give a clue to what went wrong. The only solution we found was to reboot the BES server which would get the mails flowing back to the phones for another few hours.

We used the procedure provided by BlackBerry to make sure the BESAdmin account has the correct permissions for Exchange 2010 and even rechecked.

I would like to know if anyone has an idea of what the problem might be and how to fix this.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

EDIT(add log):
[50079] (07/21 14:24:50.381):{0xA38} 2 user(s) failed to initialize

[30520] (07/21 14:24:50.381):{0xA38} Sending REPORT_HEALTH_SCORE command to Dispatcher,

Health=0x0000000002001505, Mask=0x000000000200150F, Users=2, Servers=0

[30000] (07/21 14:24:50.381):{0xA54} [DIAG] EVENT=Register_thread, THREADID=0xA54, THREADNAME="TimerHealth"

[30000] (07/21 14:24:50.381):{0xA58} [DIAG] EVENT=Register_thread, THREADID=0xA58, THREADNAME="RegistryMonitor"

[40000] (07/21 14:25:05.585):{0xA30} [BIPP] Received datagram, Tag=6448

[45072] (07/21 14:25:05.585):{0xA30} Processed config stream from Dispatcher, Tag=6448

[40000] (07/21 14:25:07.226):{0xA30} [BIPP] Received datagram, Tag=6449

[45072] (07/21 14:25:07.226):{0xA30} Processed config stream from Dispatcher, Tag=6449

[40000] (07/21 14:25:33.759):{0xA30} [BIPP] Received datagram, Tag=6496

[45072] (07/21 14:25:33.759):{0xA30} Processed config stream from Dispatcher, Tag=6496

[40000] (07/21 14:25:36.321):{0xA30} [BIPP] Received datagram, Tag=6504

[45072] (07/21 14:25:36.321):{0xA30} Processed config stream from Dispatcher, Tag=6504

[40000] (07/21 14:25:36.368):{0xA30} [BIPP] Received datagram, Tag=6506

[45072] (07/21 14:25:36.368):{0xA30} Processed config stream from Dispatcher, Tag=6506

[40000] (07/21 14:25:37.493):{0xA30} [BIPP] Received datagram, Tag=6509

[45072] (07/21 14:25:37.493):{0xA30} Processed config stream from Dispatcher, Tag=6509

[50000] (07/21 14:25:37.915):{0x15E0} Controller: closing

[50000] (07/21 14:25:37.915):{0x15E0} Controller: Requested to stop

[50106] (07/21 14:25:37.993):{0x19A4} Stopping BlackBerry Mailbox Agent 2 for Server WEB01

[30000] (07/21 14:25:37.993):{0xA38} [DIAG] EVENT=Unregister_thread, THREADID=0xA38, THREADNAME="SCS"

[30000] (07/21 14:25:37.993):{0xA54} [DIAG] EVENT=Unregister_thread, THREADID=0xA54, THREADNAME="TimerHealth"

[40000] (07/21 14:25:37.993):{0xA30} SRPClientSessionReceiver thread stopped

[30000] (07/21 14:25:37.993):{0xA30} [DIAG] EVENT=Unregister_thread, THREADID=0xA30, THREADNAME="BIPPa_ClientSessionReceiver"

[30293] (07/21 14:25:37.993):{0xA34} SRP connection dropped

[30293] (07/21 14:25:37.993):{0xA34} [BIPPa] Connection dropped, Error=0

[40000] (07/21 14:25:37.993):{0xA3C} BIPPa_ClientReceiver thread stopped

[30000] (07/21 14:25:37.993):{0xA3C} [DIAG] EVENT=Unregister_thread, THREADID=0xA3C, THREADNAME="BIPPa_ClientReceiver"

[40000] (07/21 14:25:37.993):{0xA34} SRPClientSession thread stopped

[30000] (07/21 14:25:37.993):{0xA34} [DIAG] EVENT=Unregister_thread, THREADID=0xA34, THREADNAME="BIPPa_ClientSession"

[40507] (07/21 14:25:38.914):{0x15E0} ExtUDPLogThread: Code on closing = 0

[30000] (07/21 14:25:38.914):{0x15E0} [DIAG] EVENT=Unregister_thread, THREADID=0x15E0, THREADNAME="ExtUDPLogThread"

[40000] (07/21 14:25:39.461):{0xA1C} [EXTS] BlackBerry Extension(1) disconnected.

[30000] (07/21 14:25:39.461):{0xA40} [DIAG] EVENT=Unregister_thread, THREADID=0xA40, THREADNAME="StarterThread"

[30000] (07/21 14:25:39.461):{0xA44} [DIAG] EVENT=Unregister_thread, THREADID=0xA44, THREADNAME="StarterThread"

[30000] (07/21 14:25:39.461):{0xA48} [DIAG] EVENT=Unregister_thread, THREADID=0xA48, THREADNAME="StarterThread"

[30000] (07/21 14:25:39.461):{0xA4C} [DIAG] EVENT=Unregister_thread, THREADID=0xA4C, THREADNAME="StarterThread"

[30000] (07/21 14:25:39.461):{0xA50} [DIAG] EVENT=Unregister_thread, THREADID=0xA50, THREADNAME="StarterThread"
[30000] (07/21 14:25:39.461):{0x9FC} [DIAG] EVENT=Unregister_thread, THREADID=0x9FC, THREADNAME="GlobalStatsThread"

[30000] (07/21 14:25:39.461):{0xA00} [DIAG] EVENT=Unregister_thread, THREADID=0xA00, THREADNAME="SCSWorkerThread"

[30000] (07/21 14:25:39.461):{0xA58} [DIAG] EVENT=Unregister_thread, THREADID=0xA58, THREADNAME="RegistryMonitor"

[30000] (07/21 14:25:39.461):{0x9E4} [DIAG] EVENT=Unregister_thread, THREADID=0x9E4, THREADNAME="PFContactMonitor"

[30065] (07/21 14:25:45.756):{0x19A4} BlackBerry Mailbox Agent 2 for Server WEB01 shutdown complete
====== END OF LOG ======

Comment: How many Blackberry users do you have? How many databases do you have? I still think it might be related to permissions. Can you paste the output of this command in EMS? Get-MailboxDatabase | Get-ADPermission -user besadmin | ft Identity,User,Deny,AccessRights,Inherited   Also, have you used your free support call to RIM yet? You get 1 free call when you register for BES Express.

Answer (score 1):

It may be due to the throttling policy. The official BES install instructions are wrong when they tell you how to create the throttling policy. If you followed those directions, then issue this command in EMS:

> Get-ThrottlingPolicy BESPolicy | Set-ThrottlingPolicy -RCAMaxConcurrency $null

If you did not create a policy using RIM's instructions, then try this:

> Get-ThrottlingPolicy | where {$_.IsDefault -eq $true} | Set-ThrottlingPolicy -RCAMaxConcurrency $null

Comment: Ok, the BESPolicy was not created so i just did that now, i'm going to continue to monitor and see if that fixed the problem. thanks.
If you have any more ideas i'd be glad to hear them.

Comment: Since the throttling policy wasn't created, I'm wondering what else may have been missed. I recommend working through the preinstallation tasks on this document again just to make sure everything to prepare your Exchange server has been done http://docs.blackberry.com/en/admin/deliverables/14335/BlackBerry_Enterprise_Server_Express_for_Microsoft_Exchange-Installation_and_Configuration_Guide--984521-0120054149-001-5.0.1-US.pdf

Comment: Thank you, it seems that the BESPolicy was not the issue because it stopped working again. This time i checked the BES MAGT logfile and found something weird. It's like if something is forcing the Mail Agent to shutdown. Still not sure how or why but i'm checking that now. i would post some of the logfile but the character limit per comment stops me from doing that.

Comment: Edit your question and paste the logs in there.

Comment: As a quick fix i made a batch file to stop and start the Blackberry Controller - Dispatcher - Router services. Added that to a task to run every 1 hour and i'm checking how that works out while i try to find out why the SRP connection gets droped. Because the server was stopping every 3-5 hours.