# Blackberry Enterprise Server Express & Exchange 2010 Management Console

Tags: exchange-2010, bes

I spent the whole day installing BES on an old W2003 R2 server to discover that the Server running BES requires EMC to be installed. Alas it seems that EMC for Exchange 2010 is not available in a 32bit version.  Anyway around this?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to install EMC for Exchange 2010. You need to install this:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e17e7f31-079a-43a9-bff2-0a110307611e&displaylang=en

You probably want to check the BES installation guide:
http://docs.blackberry.com/en/admin/deliverables/14335/BlackBerry_Enterprise_Server_Express_for_Microsoft_Exchange-Installation_and_Configuration_Guide--984521-0120054149-001-5.0.1-US.pdf

Comment: Have that installed already. And read the docs.  Found some info on forums earlier saying EMC was needed on the BES server to fix my "MailstoreExchange::Initialize - Error in MAPInitialize, result=0x80040106" error hence my question.

Comment: I've got BES Express installed without EMC. It is on a 64-bit server though. I know there is no way to install EMC for 2010 on a 32 bit server (I struggled with this with a BackupExec install). Look at my solution here: http://serverfault.com/questions/162668/blackberry-enterpise-server-5-0-with-exchange-2010-stops-delivering-emails-afte/162674#162674 There's a problem with the trottling policy setup in RIM's documentation that could cause problems.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the suggestions in your other thread but problem remains.

Comment: You are running BES Express 5.0, correct?

Comment: Yes Correct. I managed to rid the mapi error by sending an email to the BESAdmin account but then ran into other problems so gave up as we dumping blackberries shortly anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There's a newer free version of BES available which supports installation on an x64 machine running Windows 2008.  You can get it from the BlackBerry site.

Comment: Our Exchange server runs on a new 2008 R2 server. As we will be switching to Iphones in the next 2 or 3 months we hoped to be able to run bes on the older unused W2003 R2 server as a temporary measure.  I would still prefer to get it working on W2003 if its possible - If not we will have to install on the exchange server itself.  Thanks.